# Sort-of converse of Kolmogorov zero-one theorem

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, polynomials, ergodic-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. The Kolmogorov zero-one theorem states that

> Suppose we have independent random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$. Then $\forall \ A \in \bigcap_n \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...)$, $P(A) = 0$ or $1$.

If we choose $X_k = 1_{A_k}$ for events $A_1, A_2, ...$, then we have:

> Suppose we have independent events $A_1, A_2, ...$. Then $\forall \ A \in \bigcap_n \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...)$, $P(A) = 0$ or $1$.

Now, is this following conjecture true? If not, can it be modified slightly to be true?

> **Conjecture**: Suppose we have events $A_1, A_2, ...$ s.t. $\forall \ A \in \bigcap_n \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...)$, $P(A) = 0$ or $1$. There exists an independent sequence of events $B_1, B_2, ...$ s.t.
>
> $$\bigcap_n \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...) = \bigcap_n \sigma(B_n, B_{n+1}, ...) \tag{*}$$

---

I think [there exists a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912914/) $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ s.t. $A_{f(n)}$'s are independent so we can choose $B_n = A_{f(n)}$. Is that true? Why/Why not? If not, how else can I prove or disprove the conjecture above? If it is true, I think it can be proven by modifying the [proof of the Kolmogorov 0-1 Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296892) (for events).

---

**Perhaps one of these subsequences of sets is independent:**

$$A_n$$

$$A_{2n}, A_{2n+1}$$

$$A_{3n}, A_{3n+1}, A_{3n+2}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$A_{mn}, A_{mn+1}, A_{mn+2}, ..., A_{mn+(m-1)}$$

$$\vdots$$

I think we have that

$$\bigcap_n \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...) = \bigcap_n \sigma(A_{mn+i}, A_{m(n+1)+i}, ...)$$

where $m \in \mathbb N$ and $i \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., m-1\}$.

---

**Based on what @FedorPetrov pointed out**, it seems like we need $f(n)$'s s.t.

$$\sigma(A_{f(n)}, A_{f(n+1)}...) \subseteq \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...) \tag{**}$$

which I guess is true **if (and only if?) $f(n) \ge n$**.

---

**Other possible candidates for $f(n)$:** (assume the variables are s.t. $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is satisfied. If need be, $(**)$ or $f(n) \ge n$ too.)

1. $\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_i n^i$
2. $2^n, 3^n, ...$
3. $\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i c_i^n$
4. $\lfloor{t^n}\rfloor, \lceil{t^n}\rceil$ ([I guess $t > e^{1/e}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%27s_problem))
5. $\lfloor{\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i c_i^n}\rfloor, \lceil{\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i c_i^n}\rceil$
6. $\lfloor{\text{linear combination of trigonometric functions}}\rfloor, \lceil{\text{linear combination of trigonometric functions}}\rceil$
7. $\lfloor{\text{Some linear combination of the above}}\rfloor, \lceil{\text{Some linear combination of the above}}\rceil$

---

**Assuming the conjecture is true**, I guess it's not necessary to find $f(n)$ that works for all possible sequences of events $A_1, A_2, ...$ because such $f(n)$ may not even exist.

---

**To disprove the conjecture**: There's of course showing that any sequence that satisfies $(*)$ will not be independent, but I have a feeling it's more of showing that any independent sequence will never satisfy $(*)$.

Something that might help: we could show that $\forall \ A \in \bigcap_n \sigma(A_{f(n)}, A_{f(n+1)}, ...), P(A) = 0$ or $1$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb N, A_{f(n)}, A_{f(n+1)}, ...$ is not independent, but I'm not quite sure that the conjecture is disproved because we could construct some $B_n$'s that look like:

1. $$B_n = A_{n+1} \setminus A_n$$
2. $$B_n = A_{n} \setminus A_{n-1}, A_0 = \emptyset$$
3. $$B_n = \bigcap_m A_{mn}$$
4. $$B_n = \bigcup_m A_{mn}$$
5. $$B_{2n} = \bigcap_m A_{mn}, B_{2n+1} = \bigcup_m A_{mn}$$
6. $$B_n = \limsup_m A_{mn}$$
7. $$B_n = \liminf_m A_{mn}$$
8. $$B_{2n} = \limsup_m A_{mn}, B_{2n+1} = \liminf_m A_{mn}$$

Not to say of course that any of those $B_n$'s satisfy $(*)$ but that $B_n$ need not be in the form $A_{f(n)}$.

---

Borel-Cantelli:

1. If $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty \to 0 = P(\limsup A_n) = P(\limsup A_{mn}) \ \forall m \in \mathbb N$. Hence $B_m = \limsup A_{mn}$ is independent.
2. If $\sum_n P(A_n) = \infty$, then maybe [this extension of Borel-Cantelli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312151/)? Not quite sure I understand it or how it would be helpful. I don't think we can conclude anything if we have $P(\limsup A_n)$.
3. Then there's the case of $\sum_n P(A_n) = \infty$ but the conditions earlier aren't satisfied.

---

Based on: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605301

Comment: Did you check this in some simple situation where the tail sigma-algebra is still trivial, e.g. $X_n$ is a Markov chain on $\{0,1\}$, and $A_n=1_{X_n=0}$? How would you construct your events $B_n$ then?

Comment: @SergueiPopov I'm guessing you mean $A_n = (X_n = 0)$ I'm actually not too familiar with Markov chains. Do you mean that $P(X_n = a | \mathscr F_m) = P(X_n = a | X_m)$ for $a \in \{0, 1\}$ and $m < n$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $A_n=\{X_0=0\}$. Well, then you probably need to read something about tail sigma-algebras for Markov chains and beyond; see e.g. the chapter about ergodic theory in "Probability" of Durrett.

Comment: @SergueiPopov Oh okay thanks. What exactly are the implications though? Are you sure the assumptions are satisfied? Is there something wrong with assuming existence of such independent sequence?

Comment: Well,  existence of such independent sequence is something that should be proved...   In general, I'm rather sceptical, since there are a lot of examples of nonindependent sequences with trivial tail sigma-algebra.

Comment: @SergueiPopov Sorry for the confusion. I'm thinking proof by contradiction to disprove the converse. If we assume there exists such an independent sequence then we have something which contradicts one of the assumptions. To prove the converse, I guess if proof by construction doesn't work, maybe contradiction: Assume that all the subsequences given above are not independent then we have something which contradicts one of the assumptions.

Comment: @SergueiPopov 'nonindependent sequences with trivial tail sigma-algebra' For example?

Comment: Even if such function $f(n)$ exists, how does it imply equality of sigma-algebras?

Comment: @BCLC: please see Durrett's book, chapter on Ergodic Theory

Comment: @FedorPetrov Ummmm I think the proof for $A_{f(n)}$ is very similar to the proof for, say, $A_{2n}$, which I think relies on $\sigma(A_{2n}, A_{2n+1}...) \subseteq \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...)$. Similarly, I think we can say that $\sigma(A_{f(n)}, A_{f(n+1)}...) \subseteq \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...)$, which I guess is true assuming $f(n) \ge n$. Ah cool insight. Thanks ^-^

Comment: @SergueiPopov Very well. Thanks ^-^

Comment: I would not call that a converse of Kolmogorov theorem. Because this theorem is not really a statement about the "set-theoretic" $\sigma$-fields $\sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, \ldots)$, but rather about their completions $\bmod \mathbb{P}$ (the independance assumption is a "$\bmod P$" property).

Comment: To elaborate my previous comment. Say that a decreasing sequence of $\sigma$-fields $({\cal F}_n)$ (a reversed filtration) is of *product type* if there exists some independent random variables $A_n$ such that ${\cal F}_n = \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, \ldots)$. Kolmogorov's theorem says: if $({\cal F}_n)$ is of product type, then $({\cal F}_n)$ is tail-trivial. So its converse is: if $({\cal F}_n)$ is tail-trivial, then $({\cal F}_n)$ is of product type. It is wrong because a product type reversed filtration has local constraints. But there is a lot of interesting things to say about this converse.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Edited. Happy now? :P

Comment: As I commented when you posted this on stats.stackexchange.com,if you require the events $B_n$ to be independent in an "interesting" way (I.e. non-null) then the conjecture is false.  Moreover I think you should begin with a simplification.

Comment: @P.Windridge Seriously? Care to prove it?

Comment: For the case where you want the independent events to have probability bounded away from zero it was essentially in the lecture notes i linked to.  I accept there is more work to do if you want to allow the probabilities for your independent events to tend to zero.  As you allude to the situation is less clear if the probabilities are summable.

Comment: I should add that it's a nice conjecture, but intuitively the tail sigma algebra from dependent events can simply be much smaller than that coming independent events (assuming they are independent in a non-boring manner)

Comment: I think the key question here is "Suppose that $\mathcal{G}$ is a [non-countably-generated] $\mathbb{P}$-trivial tail $\sigma$-algebra [coming from non-null events which may be dependent].  Can $\mathcal{G}$ be realised as the tail $\sigma$-algebra for some null events?"  (I think the answer is "no", but can't see an easy example right now).

Comment: I don't understand your response to Fedor Petrov. I see that $(A_{f(n)}, A_{f(n+1)},\dots) \subseteq (A_{f(n)}, A_{f(n)+1}, \dots)$ but how do you get an equality, instead of just an inclusion?

Comment: @WillSawin Been awhile so I forgot the context. I think I meant that as a necessary condition for such $f$, if it exists. Would that make sense?

Comment: @WillSawin (2 years later) I think I remember now. Indeed, it does not get an equality. That was the insight, and it was cool.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there can be such a selection function $f$.

Define $A_i$ through independent events $C_i$ and $D_i$, each of which occurs with $50\%$ chance, as follows.
$A_1=D_1$ and for $i\ge 2$, if $C_i$, then $A_i=D_i$, otherwise $A_i=A_{i-1}$.
If $A \in \bigcap_n \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...)$, then $P(A) = 0$ or $1$ should hold, with a similar proof as for the Kolmogorov Zero-One Theorem.
On the other hand, no $A_i$ and $A_j$ are independent.

Comment: what do you mean by 'if $C_i$' ? You mean if $\omega \in C_i$, then $A_i = D_i$ ?

Comment: $C_i$ is an event, so I mean if $C_i$ occurs. Each of $C_i$ and $D_i$ are like independent coin tosses - if $C_i$ comes up heads, $A_i$ is unchanged, if $C_i$ comes up tails, $A_i$ gets the value of $D_i$.

Comment: Right. Anyway, how does that prove or suggest that such $f$ does not exist?

Comment: None of the $A_i$'s are independent, so whatever your $f$ is, already $A_{f(1)}$ and $A_{f(2)}$ won't be independent.

Comment: Ah thanks, domotorp. Dumb question: If $C_i$ and $D_i$ are independent, how can the choice of $A_i$ depend on whether or not $\omega \in C_i$?

Comment: Wait $D_i = C_i^C$ a.s.? If not, why? If so, then I think $C_i$ is independent of itself (well I know this is true if we have surely instead of a.s. Does this not hold if we have only a.s.?). Hence, the $A_i$'s are independent and hence pairwise independent...?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with most of your notation. What is $\omega$? What is $C_i^C$? Anyhow, every $C_i$, and every $D_i$ is an independent coin toss. Also, $A_2$ obviously depends on $A_1$, as with $75\%$ probability they are the same, with $25\%$ probability they differ.

Comment: domotorp, $\omega$ is a sample point in the sample space $\Omega$ in the prob space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ so we could have $\omega \in C_1$, $\omega \in C_2$, $\omega \in D_3$, etc. $C_i^C = \Omega \setminus C_i$. If $P(D_i) = 1 - P(C_i) = 0.5$, then $P(D_i) = P(C_i) = 0.5$. We know that $P(C_i^C) = 0.5$ so $D_i$ and  $C_i^C$ have the same probability. If $C_i$ and $D_i$ are independent, then I believe $C_i$ and $C_i^C$ are independent. Hence, $C_i$ is independent of itself. If this is the case, then $D_i$ is independent of itself. Hence $A_1, A_2, ...$ are independent?

Comment: Wait, how about we just remove the independence assumption in your answer so we can have a proof that such $f$ doesn't exist...?

Comment: $C_i$ and $C_i^C$ are not independent.

Comment: But you agree with everything I said before that?

Comment: Yes, to everything before that.

Comment: domotorp, to clarify, 1 $C_i$ and $D_i$ are independent? 2 $P(C_i) = P(D_i) = P(C_i^C) = 0.5$ ?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: domotorp, how does your answer rely on $C_i$ and $D_i$ being independent?

Comment: If, say, $C_i=D_i$, then $P(A_i)\lim 1$, which is different from what I had in mind, but it might also serve as a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mind removing independence so we can have a counterexample without my counterarguments, whether or not correct?

Comment: Yes, I do mind removing it, because I believe that my argument is correct with independence and I'm not sure what happens without it.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread other comment. You're not very certain about removing independence assumption. I'm going to reread comments later lol