# Kolmogorov 0-1 law counter examples for almost independent variables

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

According to Kolmogorov 0-1 law, if $ \left(X_{i}\right)_{i=1}^{\infty} $ are independent, then the tail sigma algebra is trivial. I want to construct such variables which are "almost independent": k wise independent, such that the tail sigma algebra is non-trivial.

We can look at $ X_{i}\sim U\left( \left\{ 0,1\right\} \right) $ where we set $ X_{a\left(k+1\right)}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{k}X_{a\left(k+1\right)-i} $ in order to construct k-wise independent variables, but I can't find an event in their tail sigma algebra which is not trivial. Maybe this is not a good (enough) example of k-wise independent variables, but I can't think of a better one.

Comment: crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4515647/588557

Comment: Relevant? [Link 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227075/sort-of-converse-of-kolmogorov-zero-one-theorem) [Link 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227172/is-the-limsup-or-liminf-of-n-wise-independent-events-independent) [Link 3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229136/do-we-have-independence-if-we-let-the-indices-of-the-events-increase)

Answer (score 10):

Let $(Y_1,\dots, Y_k)$ be a random $k$-tuple uniformly distributed in $(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)^k$.

Let $X_i = \sum_{j=1}^k i^j Y_j \in \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.

Then the $X_i$ are $k$-wise independent (and uniformly distributed on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$), since the linear map sending $(Y_1,\dots, Y_k)$ to $(X_{i_1},\dots, X_{i_k})$ is given by a $k\times k$ integer matrix with nonzero (Vandermonde) determinant, and such maps preserve the uniform measure on the torus $(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)^k$.

(One way to check this is by Weyl's criterion, that $X_{i_1},\dots, X_{i_k}$ are uniformly distributed if and only if the expectation of $e^{ 2 \pi i \sum_{j=1}^k X_{i_j} n_j}$ is $0$ for all tuples $n_1,\dots, n_k$ of integers other than $0,\dots, 0$. This follows from uniform distribution of the $Y_1,\dots, Y_k$ because $\sum_{j=1}^k X_{i_j} n_j = \sum_{\ell=1}^k (\sum_{j=1}^k n_j i_j^\ell) Y_\ell $ and $(\sum_{j=1}^k n_j i_j^\ell)$ are integers not all $0$ by the nonvanishing of the Vandermonde. Another way is to note that each possible value of $X_1,\dots, X_k$ has a number of preimages equal to the absolute value of the determinant which cancels the inverse factor of the determinant of the derivative, which is the inverse of the Vandermonde determinant, from the change-of-variables formula in integration.)

But we can write $ k! Y_k = \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} X_{i-j}$ for any $i$ so $k! Y_k$ is a nonconstant function in the tail sigma-algebra.

Comment: What do you mean? To my understanding, the values of $Y_i$ are totally revealed given k different $X_i$-s, so specifically the values of $Y_k$ and $k!Y_k$ are revealed (and thus constant) in the tail sigma algebra of $X_i$ (?). What am I missing?

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski I mean $Y_k$ is (1) a nonconstant function and (2) (measurable) in the tail sigma algebra, so e.g. $k! Y_k \in [0,1/2]$ is a nontrivial even in the tail sigma algebra.

Comment: Why isn't it constant in the tail sigma algebra? Can't we just get the value of $Y_k$ using any k $X_i$-s (which we have infinite of in the tail)?

Comment: This is a very nice construction. I have only taken the liberty to make a couple of edits in your answer. Can you detail why "such maps preserve the uniform measure on the torus"?

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski First, we can't actually get the value of $Y_k$ itself using any $k$ $X_i$'s. For example adding $1/2$ to $Y_{k-1}$ and $Y_k$ does not change the value of $X_i$. Second, we absolutely can get $k! Y_k$ using $k$ of the $X_i$s, at least if they are consecutive. I didn't (intend to) say it was not constant with respect to the sigma algebra, a term I'm not familiar with. I said it was not constant, and, also, in the sigma algebra. I think by "in the sigma algebra" I mean the same thing you mean by "constant in the sigma algebra", i.e. measurable with respect to a sigma algebra.

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski you are confusing quantifiers. conditioned on the outcome of $X_1,\dots$, $Y_k$ is determined by the tail sigma algebra. However, any event determined by the tail sigma algebra is constant when you condition on $X_1,\dots$. However, as Will points out, the event that $Y_k \in [0,1/2]$ is determined by the sigma algebra but occurs with probability $1/2$ (implying non-triviality).

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sure, added two proofs, one more elementary but sketchier.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have a reference concerning "a number of preimages equal to the absolute value of the determinant"? This is probably something simple, and yet, it would be good to see related matters in such a reference.

Comment: Why can we write $k!Y_k$ the way you did in your last paragraph though?

Comment: Also, I think that a uniform distribution on  $ \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z} $ doesn't exist, does it?

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski (1) One just plugs in and simplifies. (2) I'm using a "modulo" symbol, not a "set minus" symbol.

Comment: @WillSawin Regarding (1), I fail to do so. Upon manual plugging I get for k=3, i=5 $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(-1\right)^{j}{k-1 \choose j}X_{i-j}=2Y_{2}+24Y_{3}$, for k=3,i=4 I get $2Y_{2}+18Y_{3}$ (multiplying by $k!$ won't make the $Y_2$ vanish, would it?).

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski Sorry, I made an off-by-one error, it should just be $\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^k \binom{k}{j} X_{i-j}$  so the coefficient of $Y_2 $ is $i^2 - 3 (i-1)^2 + 3 (i-2)^2 - (i-3)^2=0$

Answer (score 6):

There is no such counterexample. Indeed, by [Theorem 1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3532076#metadata_info_tab_contents), any strong mixing sequence obeys the $0$-$1$ law. Also, any [$m$-dependent](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/M-dependent-process) sequence is obviously strong mixing, for any integer $m\ge0$, and hence must obey the $0$-$1$ law.

Comment: do you mean $k$-independent and any natural $k>1$?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the concept of strong mixing, so take this comment with a  grain of salt. While my example is indeed a strong mixing, I can think of a sequence of random variables such that ANY (K+1) of them are dependent, for example using linear equations with k variables, am I wrong?

Comment: @ZachHunter : I do not know what $k$-independent would mean. I have added a link to the definition of $m$-dependence.

Comment: Naturally speaking, k-wise independence means that given a variable $X_i$, knowing the values of any (other) k-1 variables, does not give more information about $X_i$. Formally, it means that (for discrete variables) $$ \prod_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n_{i}}=a_{i}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{k}X_{n_{i}}=a_{i}\right) $$

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski : The definition of strong mixing is given in the paper linked in my answer. As for your example, I cannot discern any definition of a sequence of random variables there. If you meant $Y_n:=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k X_{n-i}$, where the $X_i$'s are independent $U(\{0,1\})$, then the sequence $(Y_n)$ is $m$-dependent for $m=k-1$ and therefore must obey the 0-1 law.

Comment: In my post I "override" $ X_i $ (so in each k+1 variables, the first k are $\sim U\left(\left\{ 0,1\right\} \right)$, and the one after them is determined from the k $X_i$s before it. In your example in the above comment, the variables $ Y_n $ are not well defined, but the natural fixing of them makes them totally independent, as $X_{i}\oplus X_{j}$ is also $\sim U\left(\left\{ 0,1\right\} \right)$.

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski : I still do not understand the definition in your example. In particular: (i) What is $a$ there? (ii) What is the joint distribution of the $X_i$'s? (iii) What do you mean by "override"? Etc, etc. I also do not understand (a) why you think the $Y_n$'s are not well defined; (b) how you propose to "fix" them; (c) how a fact about a marginal one-dimensional distribution can imply such a statement about a joint distribution as a statement of independence.

Comment: $a$ is any integer. To clarify, this is my example for any $i\not\equiv0\pmod{k+1}$, we define  $X_{i}\sim U\left(\left\{ 0,1\right\} \right)$, and for $i\equiv0\pmod{k+1}$ we define $X_{i}=\bigoplus_{j=1}^{k}X_{i-j} $

Comment: In your example the $Y_n$ are not well defined because you access non defined indices (what is $Y_1$?). The natural fixing is $ Y_{n}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{k}X_{n+i} $, and this way they are indeed totally independent (to the best of my understanding), as you can't infer anything about $Y_{i}$'s value given $Y_{j}$'s value.

Comment: @PetriKattilakoski : The definition in your comment is better than the one in the OP. Still, are the $X_i$'s with $i\ne0\mod k+1$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are i.i.d.

Comment: Relevant? [Link 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227075/sort-of-converse-of-kolmogorov-zero-one-theorem) [Link 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227172/is-the-limsup-or-liminf-of-n-wise-independent-events-independent) [Link 3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229136/do-we-have-independence-if-we-let-the-indices-of-the-events-increase)

Comment: @BCLC : Thank you for the links.